# How do I get the correct application.xml file to appear in my EAR file using Maven?

Tags: maven, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 with the Maven EAR plugin (v2.7).  I'm having trouble getting the proper application.xml file included in my EAR distribution.  Although a target/application.xml is correctly generated ...

```xml
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>Orders</display-name>
  <description>Runs periodic jobs to process DIDO orders.</description>
  <module>
    <java>lib/myclient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</java>
  </module>
</application>
```

The application.xml file that is actually inserted in my EAR file (in the META-INF directory) is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application id="Application_ID">
    <display-name>orders-ear</display-name>
</application>
```

What gives?  Below is the pom.xml file for my EAR project

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mainco.myco</groupId>
        <artifactId>orders</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>orders-ear</artifactId>
    <name>Orders :: Enterprise Application</name>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <description>Orders EAR</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mainco.myco</groupId>
        <artifactId>myclient</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <displayName>Orders</displayName>
                <description>Runs periodic jobs to process DIDO orders.</description>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir> 
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>org.mainco.myco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myclient</artifactId>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>       
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

How do I get my EAR to include the right application.xml file?  Thanks, - Dave